# Crop image before sending as DataURL

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a canvas that is edited by a user (some drag and drop stuff), and it has some instructions printed in text on it. I want to save the image without that text.

I am using KeneticJS. The size will always be the same and the text is at the bottom of the image, so I was thinking if I could just crop that out that would work fine. I am passing the image as a dataURL to my solution, is it possible to crop the image before sending it as a data url?

It would be great if I could just say dataURL.crop(height, width); or something.

Here is my code which, on button press, sends the image as a data url to my filemaker solution.

```js
     bGroup.on('click touchstart', function(){
      stage.toDataURL({
             callback: function(dataUrl) {
                   var myParam = encodeURIComponent(dataUrl.split(',').pop());
                   theURL = 'fmp://$/" & Get(FileName)& "?script=MoistureMap_Done&param=' + myParam;
                   window.location= theURL;
                   bDone.fill('green');
                   buttonLayer.draw();
             }});
     
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no direct way of clipping your text, but it's not difficult:

1. Create an image from the dataURL (or use the texted image if you still have access to it).
2. Create a new in-memory canvas: document.createElement('canvas');
3. Resize the canvas to your desired clipped size: canvas.width=10; canvas.height=10;
4. Draw the image from #1 onto the canvas: context.drawImage
5. The text at the bottom of the image will automatically be clipped since the in-memory canvas is smaller than the incoming image.
6. Pull the dataurl of the in-memory canvas: canvas.toDataURL